# Hide table when current date time passed assigned deadline in xml template odoo 12

Tags: xml, datetime, templates, odoo

I want to apply condition that when current date passed survey answer deadline then respective table invisible. For this i try below code but's its not working. Can anybody provide me exact solution for my problem.

```
<tr t-if="datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') &gt; ans.date_create">
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ans.date_create` to get the current datetime and replace the time in place.

```
t-if="ans.date_create.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0) &gt; ans.date_create"
```